# Questions about evaluating Dyson series

Tags: functional-analysis, quantum-mechanics

I have some questions about Dyson series in quantum theory. For perturbed hamiltonian $H=H_0+\lambda V(t)$, we have the following differential equations in interaction picture.
$$
       i \hbar \frac{d}{dt} |\psi_I(t)\rangle=\lambda V_I(t)|\psi_I(t) \rangle 
$$
Integrating iteratively gives the following dyson series.
$$
       |\psi_I(t)\big>=|\psi_I(0)\big>+\frac{\lambda}{i\hbar}\int_0^tV_I(t')|\psi_I(0)\rangle dt'+(\frac{\lambda}{i\hbar})^2\int_0^tV_I(t') \int_0^{t'}V_I(t'')|\psi_I(0)\rangle dt''dt'+...
$$
I have several questions about this equation.

1. First, is it right to understand this integral in sense of Bochner integral? I think so because we are integrating 'vectors' in hilbert space.
2. $V_I(t)$ is in general unbounded operator. Is it okay to interchange order of integration and operator $V_I(t)$? (That is, is $\int V_I=V_I\int$ valid?)
3. I think it is possible for $V_I(t')|\psi_I(0)\rangle\notin D(V_I(t))$ or $V_I(t')V_I(t'')|\psi_I(0)\rangle\notin D(V_I(t))$ ... to happen. Here, $D(V_I(t))$ is a domain of $V_I(t)$. If this happens, the equation above does not make sense. Is there an additional reasonable hypothesis on $V_I(t)$ that makes this not happen?

Thank you for reading these questions.

Comment: 2. $V_I(t)$ is a function (operator-valued). How could you move a function out of the integral that is using it?

Comment: 3. Shouldn't $V_I(t)$ map some Hilbert space $H$ into itself, so that $D(V_I(t))=H$ and $V_I(t')|\psi_I(0)\rangle \in H$ for $|\psi_I(0)\rangle \in H$?

Comment: 1. A Bochner integral should work, but there are probably conceptually easier definitions, like component-wise integration.

Comment: For 2,  I was asking whether I can  move $V_I(t)$ into the integral. When we do iterating procedure, the operator $V_I(t')$ just remains outside the integral.

Comment: Also, for 3, since $V_I(t)$ is generally unbouded and self-adjoint, so the domain $D(V_I(t))$ cannot be H. It is only a dense subset of H. It is dangerous to multiply two unbounded operators $A$ and $B$ because $Bv$ may not be in $D(A)$.